# Combine results from one Flowable with another

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a `Timeline` screen where I display a list of posts to the user.

I fetch those posts from a network service and I save them to a database table. I'm using `Room` together with `SQLite` as a local data source.

Since `Room` works with `RxJava` I'm just returning the list of posts as a `Flowable<List<Post>>`.

The code I'm using is :

```
@Override
public Flowable<List<Post>> loadData() {
    if (networkUtils.isOnline()) {
        disposables.add(
                localDataSource.getLastStoredId()
                        .flatMap(s -> remoteDataSource.getPosts(s))
                        .doOnNext(postItemList -> {
                            if (postItemList != null) {
                                localDataSource.savePost(postItemList);
                            }

                        })
                        .map(postItemList -> {
                            List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (PostItem postItem : postItemList) {
                                postList.add(mapper.from(postItem));
                            }
                            return postList;
                        })
                        .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                        .observeOn(schedulerProvider.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(
                                posts -> { },
                                throwable -> {}));

    }

    return localDataSource.getPostsSorted();
}
```

The only problem with this approach is this : I have a requirement to display a specific view when user has just created an account and there aren't any data left. So this really means : a) table "posts" is empty and b) I just made a network request and in the response there aren't any data.

Is there an operator I can use for such a case or is there any other way to implement this requirement ?

EDIT : `zip()` operator is not for this case and I'm not sure about `combineLatest()` but even if it worked I don't know how to write the code since there's also the check for the network state and other than that one Flowable returns a list of items while the other just subscribes which means I will have a nested subscription. Or how should I combine them and add one to the `disposables` variable so I can clear the subscription ?

Comment: `postItemList != null` is redundant since rxjava2 does not accept emitting nulls

Comment: Is it because query not return any result set and  exception result set not fund exception is throwing or something similar? ?

Comment: @lib4 yes! I should somehow know what response I got from the network request so I can display the empty view in case of no data in the response